# How to use adobe's pdf reader on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, plugins, adobe-reader

I want to disable the pdf plugin built into Google Chrome, and use the official one by adobe. I was able to disable the built in plugin, I don't know where to get the alternative plugin. Where can I get it?

Comment: look in the google chrome extension store

Answer (score 1):

You can also download the oficial PDF from Adobe. Just go to their website and download Adobe Reader .deb: http://get.adobe.com/br/reader/otherversions/

Because if you've disabled the built-in PDF viewer, Chrome will use Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader to display PDFs

More info on this can be found here: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142056

Comment: He asked about the pdf reader...

Answer (score 0):

the latest solution can be found here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142056?hl=en
But most oficial Adobe pdf plugin is charged.Is it possiable for us to find other pdf add-on to enable Chrome to read PDF files?After searching from internet ,I got [pdf add-on](http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/csharp-imaging/pdf-reading/) for web viewer ,but It seems not working.
Any free pdf add-on works ?

Comment: It is difficult to tell if you are asking a new question or not.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This both a link-only answer as well as a new question. Please include more information about what steps to take in case that page goes offline. If you have new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. Also: what do you mean by "oficial Adobe pdf plugin is charged"?